# Do I need to hide my S3 image URL from users?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

This is my first time ever using S3, and I have a question that I haven't been able to find an answer to. I have images like this `<img src='https://mybucket.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/16079745842336'` throughout my site, and I'm wondering if I need to hide that URL? I've seen some people on here explain how to, but my question is if I need to? Will people have access to anything in my bucket if they can follow that link?

Comment: Not if your security access are properly configured which, from what I heard, is not the easiest of the things to achieve. Did you took the time to read AWS own recommendations: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/security-best-practices.html

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε thanks for the link, ill look into that now

Answer (score 2):

The URL uses a hashing technique to ensure the URL cannot be modified, nor can it be abused to get other files.

Make the bucket private, By Doing this you will be safe.

- The credentials you see in the URL are may be the same as those that
  were used to create the URL. But they are safe to show the user.
- The user can only download the file during the timeframe that you
  permit, until the expiration date (which you set as part of the
  GetPreSignedUrlRequest call)
- The user cannot download any other files from the bucket

If you make the Bucket Public, then potentially any user could see other user uploaded files.

Comment: sorry I'm not sure how I missed your answer, that makes sense and ideally I'd like to be able to 'block public access', but I have a form on my website that allows users to upload images that are then displayed on on the website.

Comment: Then you should assign roles to your bucket to display the images on your website rather then making it Public.